# delphi XE8 REST Interface PUT in prestashop

Tags: rest, delphi, prestashop, delphi-xe8

I'm trying to update a manufacturer in Prestashop through the REST interface. So far I've been able to GET the information, but when I try to PUT, I Always get an HTTP 500 error.

```
try
    Memo1.Text := '<prestashop><manufacturer><id><![CDATA[804]]></id><name><![CDATA[DisneyLand]]></name></manufacturer></prestashop>';

    RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
    //authentication does not work with PUT, use token as suffix....
    RESTClient1.Authenticator := nil; //SimpleAuthenticator1;//
    //SimpleAuthenticator1.UserNameKey := 'ws_key';
    //SimpleAuthenticator1.UserName := 'HEREIGOESTHETOKEN';
    RESTRequest1.Resource := 'manufacturers';
    RESTRequest1.ResourceSuffix := '?ws_key=HEREIGOESTHETOKEN';
    RESTRequest1.Method := rmPut; //update
    RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'http://localhost/prestashop/api';
    RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('id', '804' ,pkGETorPOST , [], ctTEXT_PLAIN);
    RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('putXml', Memo1.Text,
                                pkGETorPOST , [], ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED);

    RESTRequest1.Execute;

    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse1.Content);
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Clear;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Exception message = '+E.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

I've tried the other TRESTRequestParameterKind posibilities, but no avail.

Anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : After monitoring my network with Wireshark, i noticed that if I use the TSimpleauthenticater component anywhere before, the xml is always appended with the ws_key value, resulting in a  500 server error. This happens even if I clear all the SimpleAuthenticator settings and set the Clients authenticator to nil.

I also had to set the content type to  ctTEXT_XML iso ctAPPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED when specifying th xml in the body.

Following code works :

```
procedure TForm1.BtnNewMfgClick(Sender: TObject);       //new
var
  aNode, aCNode, aCCNode : IXMLNode;
  i,j : integer;
  aXml : string;
begin
  RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
  RESTClient1.Authenticator := nil;
  SimpleAuthenticator1.UserNameKey := '';
  SimpleAuthenticator1.UserName := '';

  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'http://localhost/prestashop/api';
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'manufacturers';
  RESTRequest1.ResourceSuffix := '?schema=blank&ws_key=HEREGOESMYKEY';
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmGet;
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  aXml := RESTResponse1.Content;
  XMLDocument1.LoadFromXML(aXml);

  aNode := XMLDocument1.ChildNodes.FindNode('prestashop');
  if assigned(aNode)
  then begin
    for i := 0 to aNode.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
    begin
      aCNode := aNode.ChildNodes.Get(i);
      for j := 0 to aCNode.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
      begin
        aCCNode := aCNode.ChildNodes.Get(j);
        if aCCNode.NodeName = 'id' then aCCNode.NodeValue := ''; //cannot pass id at create
        if aCCNode.NodeName = 'active' then aCCNode.NodeValue := '1' ;
        if aCCNode.NodeName = 'name' then aCCNode.NodeValue := 'New Brand';
      end;
    end;
  end;

  XmlDocument1.SaveToXML(aXml);

  RESTRequest1.ClearBody;
  RESTRequest1.AddBody(aXml, ctTEXT_XML);
  RESTRequest1.ResourceSuffix := '?ws_key=HEREGOESMYKEY';

  RESTRequest1.Method := rmPost;
  RESTRequest1.Execute;

  //new id is returned in the contents XML id tag
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(RESTResponse1.Content);
end;
```

Although this works in test, I'm investigating it further, because in production it has to work over https:// so the key is not exposed...

In short : Simpleauthenticator only works for GET and DELETE. Once used, PUT and POST will never work.